# Javascript returns string for OR(||) operation

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am unable to understand this.

Following is expression uses OR operator

```
var subCond1 = adj.getData('relationEnabled') == 'true' || adj.getData('unhideIfHidden') || adj.getData('hlFixed') == 'true';
```

I am expecting that since it is OR operation, it should return boolean true/false, but instead I get string 'false' as a result.

Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: @Sirko: No, `()` will make no difference to the resulting value.

Comment: Someone should write that using the && operator. lol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, that's just one of the features of `||` in JavaScript, and it's deliberate. It **doesn't** return a boolean (necessarily), it works like this: It evaluates the left-hand operand and if that operand is **truthy**, it returns it; otherwise, it evalutes and returns the right-hand operand.

So what's "truthy"? Anything that isn't "falsy". :-) The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. Anything else is truthy.

If you *need* a boolean, just `!!` the result:

```
var subCond1 = !!(adj.getData('relationEnabled') == 'true' || adj.getData('unhideIfHidden') || adj.getData('hlFixed') == 'true');
```

...but you frequently don't need to bother.

This behavior of `||` is really useful, particularly (I find) when dealing with object references that may be `null`, when you want to provide a default:

```
var obj = thisMayBeNull || {};
```

Now, `obj` will be `thisMayBeNull` if it's truthy (non-`null` object references are truthy), or `{}` if `thisMayBeNull` is falsy.

More in this article on my blog: [*JavaScript's Curiously-Powerful OR Operator (`||`)*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)

Just to round things out: The `&&` operator has a similar behavior: It evaluates the left-hand operand and, if it's **falsy**, returns it; otherwise it evaluates and returns the right-hand operator. This is useful if you want an object property from a variable which may be `null`:

```
var value = obj && obj.property;
```

`value` will be the value of `obj` if `obj` is *falsy* (for instance, `null`), or the value of `obj.property` if `obj` is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript returns the first operand that has a truthy value, whatever that truthy value is or the value of the last operand if none before are truthy.  That is a designed feature of Javascript (yes it is different than other languages).

You can turn that into a boolean by comparing to see if it is `== true` if you want or it is sometimes done with `!!`.