# Why the Javascript logical operator behaving this way?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I have some code that explains the logical operator `||` in this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jukolej/edit?html,js,output) link.

The code is below:

```js
function say(v)
{ 
    document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML += v + "</br>";
}

say('Cat' || false);
say(1 === 1 || false);
say('' || '');
say('' || 1 === 1);
say(false || '');
say(false || false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="out" style="font-family: roboto"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know:

1. Why the first expression returns 'Cat'?
2. Why the third expression returns nothing?
3. Why the fifth expression returns nothing?

Comment: *"2. Why the third expression returns nothing? 3. Why the fifth expression returns nothing?"* They don't; they return `''` (an empty string). It's just that you can't see that with the kind of output you've used. Consider using `console.log` instead for this sort of test.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983907/javascript-returns-string-for-or-operation) that you answered answers my question also.

Comment: Er...yes...that's why I flagged it as the dupetarget.